# vertical and horizontal centering of a responsive image

Tags: css, responsive-design, centering

I've been struggling with this for several days now and I'm loosing my patience. I have checked all other questions and no solution seems to resolve my issue. 
I have a bunch of images to display in the center of the viewport. It just doesn't work for mobiles (whatever I do in some mobile screen sizes the images are not aligned). I want the image container to take 90vh as the 10vh takes fixed footer. I don't want to use flexbox. 
Please help, I'm desperate!
Thanks

```
<div class="col-1 mob mob1">
  <div class="img_mob_container">
    <img class="img_mob" src="images/mob1.png" alt="App Design 1">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-1 mob mob2">
  <div class="img_mob_container">
    <img class="img_mob" src="images/mob2.png" alt="App Design 2">
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="col-1 mob mob3">
    <div class="img_mob_container">
    <img class="img_mob" src="images/mob3.png" alt="App Design 3">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-1 mob mob4">
  <div class="img_mob_container">
    <img class="img_mob" src="images/mob4.png" alt="App Design 4">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-1 mob mob5">
  <div class="img_mob_container">
    <img class="img_mob" src="images/mob5.png" alt="App Design 5">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-1 mob mob6">
  <div class="img_mob_container">
    <img class="img_mob" src="images/mob6.png" alt="App Design 6">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-1 mob mob7">
  <div class="img_mob_container">
    <img class="img_mob" src="images/mob7.png" alt="App Design 7">
  </div>
</div>

    .mob {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      line-height: 0;
    }

    .mob1 {
      background-color: #FDBA2E; /*dark red*/
    }
    .mob2 {
      background-color: #8C3A86; /*yellow*/
    }
    .mob3 {
      background-color: #00C8D9; /*light purple*/
    }
    .mob4 {
      background-color: #C5E000; /*light green*/
    }
    .mob5 {
      background-color: #BB7F8A; /*salmon*/
    }
    .mob6 {
      background-color: #159C7E; /*purple*/
    }
    .mob7 {
      background-color: #A20F57; /*dark pink*/
    }

    .img_mob {
      margin: 5vw 37.5%;
      max-width: 600px;
      width: 25%;
    }


    /* ----------- Mobile screens ----------- */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 736px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

    .mob {
      height: 90vh;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0 15vw;
    }

    .img_mob_container {
    height: 80vh;
    margin: 5vh 0;
    }

   .img_mob {
   width: 100%;
   }
```

Comment: Without the CSS we can't really help...the first thing I would say is, *"if you're using `float`...don't"*

Comment: I haven't got a working css. I don't want to specify any height/width to the image because I want it to be resize with the screen size. And no, I don't use float.

Comment: Oh I see, you simply didn't scroll down to see css. It's there

Comment: Oops,,,thousand apologies.

Comment: I've knoocked this up...does it not work how you want? - Note you are msising a closing brace `}` in your media query.

Comment: Cheers. Nope, basically it's centered only vertically OR horizontally (depending on my experimenting) but can't get both. So for different mobile screen sizes its always too high, too low, too right or too left.